# Removing inner borders from multipolygons in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have the following multipolygon, where each polygon is a different county:
[image]

What I'd like to do is get ONLY the outline of the whole polygon, so that when I give it an outline, it is just the outermost border. Unfortunately, removing the outline color is not an option, as I'd still like to have the outline of the whole polygon available. What I'd like would be something like this:
[image]

So, how do you remove those pesky inner lines?

Comment: There's a difference between a multipolygon and a collection of polygons. By definition, the ring parts of a multipolygon cannot overlap or abut, so you have a collection of (multi)polygons, as rows in a feature class.  The Dissolve tool is used to merge neighboring shapes.

Comment: @Vince, the dissolve tool was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As @Vince had suggested, the Dissolve tool was what I was looking for.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/177179)

Comment: @TomazicM, It does. I asked how to do something, and the answer was "use the dissolve tool"

Comment: When somebody's comment provides the answer, the person who is asking the question usually writes in his comment something like: "Your comment solved my problem. If you publish it as an answer, I'll accept it and upvote it." This way credits go to the right person.

Comment: @TomazicM, I see, thanks. I will do that in the future.